# Editing Excel Spreadsheets easily with the SDK

Tags: c#, excel, sdk, openxml

is there anyone who makes use of the Microsoft Open XML SDK 2.0 for editing Excel Spreadsheet, I edited Open XML documents already by only using XML methods, but as there exists the SDK, does someone know if there are really easy methods for some essential functions? For Example the inserting of content in a cell. Also the Open XML Power Tools (published on codeplex) use mostly XML objects I think.
If you have experience, would you give me an example or a hint where I can find useful examples? I already know the site openxmldeveloper.org but also the workshop videos did not help me at all.

thanks

Sebastian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sebastian, I have not made use of this API yet, but will be using it soon.  It appears there are methods for opening docs, updating/inserting into cells.  Please check out MSDN.  Also, there is an example at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc861607(office.14).aspx

Good Luck!